# Let $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$ be distinct points on the unit circle $(|z_j| = 1).$ Prove that the $\arg z_1/z_2 = 2\arg(z_3 - z_1)/(z_3 - z_2)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that $\arg(x/y) = \arg x - \arg y$ but that leaves me with

$\arg z_1 - \arg z_2 = 2\arg(z_3 - z_1) - 2\arg(z_3 - z_2)$

Comment: I don't see how the statement in the question can be true, given that the subsequent statement you have given (with the extra factor of 2) **is** true, being a statement of the well-known circle theorem "the angle at the centre is twice the angle at the circumference"

Comment: I have added a $2$ factor which was lacking on the RHS of your formula in the title, (as remarked by @David Quinn)

Answer (score 2):

You no  need to prove it algebraically.the result follows geometrically from the theorem that angle subtended at the centre is twice the angle subtended at any point on the major segment.

Rewriting your statement as $$arg(\frac{z_1}{z_2})=2arg(\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_3-z_2})$$
[image]

Here $\theta_1$ is $arg(\frac{z_1}{z_2})$ and $\theta_2$ is $arg(\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_3-z_2})$ and the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

In general, $\arg z=\arg w$ if and only if $z/w$ is a positive real. So
consider
$$\frac{z_3-z_1}{z_3-z_2}\times\frac{z_2}{z_1}
=\frac{z_3/z_1-1}{z_3/z_2-1}.$$
As $z_3/z_1$ and $z_3/z_2$ can be almost anywhere on the unit circle, that
doesn't look real to me.

Unless you actually want $\arg z_1/z_2=2\arg(z_3-z_1)/(z_3-z_2)$.
Then consider
$$\frac{(z_3-z_1)^2}{(z_3-z_2)^2}\times\frac{z_2}{z_1}
=\frac{z_3/z_1-2+z_1/z_3}{z_3/z_2-2+z_2/z_3}.$$
As $z_3/z_1$ and $z_3/z_2$ are on the unit circle, numerator
and denominator of the last fraction are real and $<0$, so the whole thing is positive.